# specify a domain when deploying on iis

Tags: asp.net, deployment, iis-7, windows-server-2008-r2

I am deploying a web application to a windows server 2008 named jonny521 using IIS7. The domain for most applications on this server is jonny521 however one of the application's domain is jonny521.development.local and I'm not sure how the application got that domain. I want to deploy another application to the domain jonny521.development.local so that it has access to the same cookies.

Does anyone know how I can put my web application in the domain jonny521.development.local?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put an application on arbitary domain on your Iis. Just create a new website and in website properties, set the domain as the host name.

The remaining part is resolving the host name by your os so that when you navigate, you get to correct server. You can use a dns server but you can also modify the local host file (system32/drivers/etc/hosts).

Comment: The only way I could find to specify a domain is to create a new website and put the application under that as you said. I am confused still how the is an application under a website with domain jonny521 which has the domain jonny521.development.local Adding a new website with the same domain as it causes conflics so it's not an option which is lame.